# How to change the color of boot logs?

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-jessie

OS: Raspbian Jessie

How can I change the color of all the logs and text during the initial boot (and also the final shutdown) to black? (including the login user/password prompt) !?

My goal is to have a completely silent boot, where no text is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You may try add a `quiet` boot option to kernel in `/boot/cmdline.txt`, e.g.:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet
```

But for login prompt you need edit PS1 variable in `~/.bashrc` to change color or (?) disable it.